# Sending data to tastypie raises 401

Tags: jquery, django, tastypie

i tried to send some data to a tastypie poc.

i've designed my model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    icon = models.FileField(upload_to="media/img/wish-icons/")


class Wish(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('wishes.Category', blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.FloatField('Latitude', blank=True, null=True)
    lon = models.FloatField('Longitude', blank=True, null=True)
```

i've a related api.py:

```
class CategoryResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Category.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'category'
        fields = ['name', 'icon']


class WishResource(ModelResource):
    category = fields.ToManyField(CategoryResource, 'category', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Wish.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'wish'
        authorization = Authorization()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
```

i can send GET request to get a list or a detail but when i want to send data with jQuery and ajax, Firebug returns me a 401 error.

I did like the example [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html?highlight=ajax) but something goes wrong and i don't know where. It's not a cross domain request, front and tastypie have to same origin.

My ajax request looks like this:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "content": "This will prbbly be my lst post."
});
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/wish/',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  processData: false
});
```

Comment: Can you try placing error handler in the ajax call and see whats happening. Also as you CategoryResource is optional? You can get detail error log on command prompt.

Comment: Try to remove the authorization = Authorization() line.

Comment: Or add it to the categoryResource as well.

Comment: @RomainBraun: adding or removing authorization has no affect.

Comment: @Mutant. Category is not required. I tried to completely remove all content about category but nothing change. My firebug only returns 401 UNAUTHORIZED, my django console gives me "[07/Jan/2014 16:19:01] "POST /api/v1/wish/ HTTP/1.1" 401 0
" even if i set TASTYPIE_FULL_DEBUG = True :(

Comment: What is your tastypie version, and also, where did you download it from ?

Comment: Python 2.7.5 
Django 1.6.1
Tastypie 0.11.0 (latest) from pip
all dependencies are ok according to the official doc

Comment: @gorjuce are you logged in user while making this call? not sure whats causing the issue, but you might want to try out.

Comment: nop i'm lot loggued, it's a simple poc i did in 15". Really i don't undertand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything works.
I really don't know how, i played with authentication, authorization, filed types, adding/removing things and finally this is my valid app.py

```
class CategoryResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Category.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'category'
        authorization = Authorization()


class WishResource(ModelResource):
    categories = fields.ToManyField('wishes.api.CategoryResource', 'category', null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Wish.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'wish'
        authorization = Authorization()
```